# Sampling variance of regression intercept when there is no regressor

Tags: regression, estimation, variance, econometrics, regression-coefficients

Suppose we have a model $y=\beta_0+u$, where $E(u)=0$ and $Var(u)=\sigma^2$. I get the unbiased estimator $\hat\beta_0$ is just $\bar y$. But how can I get the variance of $\hat\beta_0$? Is it correct to claim that the $Var(\hat\beta_0)=Var(\bar y)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$, which is stated in the book?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I think the question title is clearer in words, and easier for others to search for, when "beta" is indicated as "regression intercept". You can reverse my edit if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you may directly apply (it sure is an overkill for this problem, as the variance of the sample mean can be derived more directly, but may help you see that it fits into the framework of linear regression) the OLS formula for the variance of the regression coefficients:
$$
Var(\hat\beta)=\sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}
$$
Now, if you only have a constant in the regression, with associated coefficient $\beta_0$ (imagine a 1 next to $\beta_0$), $X$ is just a column of $1$s, so that
$$
X'X=(1,\ldots,1)\begin{pmatrix}1\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix}=n
$$
so that 
$$
\sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}
$$

Comment: +1. Small typo. $Var(\beta)$ should be $Var(\hat{\beta})$.